# How do I iterate over an array of a custom type in Go?

Tags: go

I have a customer type I have created in my code. I have a function that is reading in a csv file and creating an array from each line.

```
type DesiredService struct {
    Name string `json:"Name"`
    Status string `json:"Status"`
}
```

If I print out the variable I have something that looks like
`[{app1 active}{app2 active}]`

I can not figure out how I would take that variable and iterate over each index. I need to take all of the entries with a Status of active and call another function to check the name against an API. I am thinking maybe I did not set the struct up correctly.

When I check the variable type it returns `[]main.DesiredService`

After reading some of the docs this is what I came up with that is not working.

```
func checkPagerDutyforService (serviceList []DesiredService) (bool){
    var serviceExist bool()
    for i, v := range serviceList {
        if v == "active" {
            checkIfServiceExist(i, serviceList)
            serviceExist = true
        } else {
            if v != "active"{
                serviceExist = false
            }
        }
    }
    return serviceExist
```

Comment: You would want to check go tour for the `range` part. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16

Comment: It's a `for` loop. What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: [`Go By Example`](https://gobyexample.com/) is a good resource for info about doing basic things in Go. Particularly the [`for/range` combo](https://gobyexample.com/range).

Comment: This is that i came up with: func checkPagerDutyforService (serviceList []DesiredService) (bool){
 var serviceExist bool()
 for i, v := range serviceList {
  if v == "active" {
   checkIfServiceExist(i, serviceList)
   serviceExist = true
  } else {
   if v != "active"{
    serviceExist = false
   }
  }
 }
 return serviceExist

Comment: `if v.Status == "active"`.  That said, that function is only going to return the active status of the _last_ entry in the serviceList, since you're overwriting the value on each loop iteration.

Comment: Also, it's `var serviceExists bool`, not `bool()`.  Parentheses imply it's a function.

Comment: @Travis It seems `checkIfServiceExist(i, serviceList)` is redundant since you're iterating over `serviceList` so obviously it exists in `serviceList`. Unless `checkIfServiceExist` is just going to do `service := serviceList[i]` and do some other check on `service` in which case you should change it to take a service directly: `checkIfService(v)`. Then it can check on any service, not only ones in lists. And `if v != "active` is redundant, if the code reaches that `else` block then by definition `v != "active`.

Comment: @Travis `return serviceExist` will only reflect the status of the final service checked. You should probably return the first active service instead, it's good to know which service to use, or `return true` when you find an active service, and `return false` otherwise. Finally, you're calling `checkIfService` but not doing anything with the return value, you're always setting it active.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> *I need to take all of the entries with a Status of active and call another function to check the name against an API.*

In Go you iterate with a [`for`](https://gobyexample.com/for) loop, usually using the [`range`](https://gobyexample.com/range) function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type DesiredService struct {
    // The JSON tags are redundant here. See below.
    Name string `json:"Name"`
    Status string `json:"Status"`
}

func main() {
    services := []DesiredService{
        DesiredService{"foo", "Active"},
        DesiredService{"bar", "Active"},
        DesiredService{"baz", "Inactive"},
    }

    for _,service := range services {
        if service.Status == "Active" {
            fmt.Printf("%#v\n", service);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `range` returns the index (ie. 0, 1, 2) and the actual element. If you want just the index it's `for i := range services` but if you want just the element it's `for _,service := range services` with the `_` telling Go that you don't want that return value.

`range` is very powerful and flexible core feature of Go. If you haven't gotten to `range`, I'd recommend stopping and reading at least [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) and [Go By Example](https://gobyexample.com/) which will cover basic functionality like this. Then read [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) for the details.

---

Note that the JSON field tags are unnecessary. JSON will already automatically marshal the field `Name` as the JSON field `Name` by default. So they can be omitted. If you wanted to change it to `name` then you'd use a tag.

---

There's a number of problems with the code you're trying.

- `v == "active"`: `v` is a DesiredService struct. To check its Status field it's `v.Status == "active"`.
- `else { if v != "active"`: This is redundant with `if v == "active"`. If you're in that `else` block by definition `v == "active"`.
- `return serviceExist`: This is set by every loop iteration, so it will only reflect the last element in `serviceList`.

Here's how you'd handle this.

```
// Just a placeholder. Presumably it will ping the service
// to ensure it's really working.
func pingService( service DesiredService ) bool {
    return true
}

func getActiveService (services []DesiredService) *DesiredService {
    for _, service := range services {
        if service.Status == "active" && pingService(service) {
            return &service
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Note that it returns immediately upon finding an active service, rather than iterating through the whole list. Once it's found a service there's no need to go further.

I've changed it to `getActiveService` for two reasons. There's nothing in here about pagers, so presumably it can handle lists of any types of services. And second, returning a bool is like saying "yes, there is an active service in this list" and the natural next question is "ok, smart ass, which one?!" Since we've gone through the work anyway, might as well return an active service.

This changes the return value a bit from a simple boolean to `*DesiredService`. "Get" functions sometimes can't get what you want. But the `DesiredService` type says you will *always* return a `DesiredService`. By making it a reference to a `DesiredService` we can return `nil` if there's no active service.

```
service := getActiveService(services);
if service != nil {
    fmt.Println(service)
} else {
    fmt.Println("No active service")
}
```

`*DesiredService` is a reference to `DesiredService` not a copy. Go will smooth out the difference between a thing and a reference to a thing, there's no special syntax for working with a reference. However, be aware that you're not working with a copy. Any changes you make to `service` will reflect on the `services` list.

```
// This will affect the entry in services as well.
service.Name = "something else"
```

[Further detailed errors are returned using the `error` type](https://gobyexample.com/errors).

---

The next step would be to roll `service.Status == "active" && pingService(service)` into [a single method on `DesiredService`](https://gobyexample.com/methods) so services know how to check themselves. Then anyone using a DesiredService doesn't need to know these details, and the details are in one place should they change.

```
func (self DesiredService) isActive() bool {
    return self.Status == "active" && self.Ping()
}
```

Pinging is also something a service should do to itself.

```
// Just a placeholder. Presumably this will ping the
// service or something.
func (self DesiredService) Ping() bool {
    return true
}
```

Then `getActiveService` asks the `service` if it is active.

```
func getActiveService (serviceList []DesiredService) *DesiredService {
    for _, service := range serviceList {
        if service.isActive() {
            return &service
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Ok I think I having a problem with the _

Comment: @Travis I've added to the answer why `checkPagerDutyforService` isn't working.

Comment: For the record, using `self` (or `this`) as the name of the method receiver is _strongly discouraged_ in Go.  That reflects a more object-oriented style, and Go is not object oriented (at least, in the traditional sense).  Typical receiver names are 1-3 characters long, often the first 1-3 characters of the type or the initials of it (so `d` or `ds` in this case).  This is especially relevant here, because your method receivers are _value_ receivers, and thus any updates to `self` _will not propagate outside that method!_  See https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-names

Comment: Also, Golint will flag "this" and "self" as invalid, for further evidence that it's not considered idiomatic Go: https://github.com/golang/lint/blob/master/lint.go#L1225

Comment: @Kaedys Thanks, I know. I disagree. I'm not a fan of shrt vrbls, contextual readability still matters even in small functions. I believe distinguishing the receiver from other variables is more important than reminding the reader that Go's object model is different; something they will quickly learn. Knowing if it's a value or reference receiver is important, clearly distinguishing between them would be a better use of a naming convention. Go has a very nice object model, they've stripped out a lot of what gets people into trouble, and I like it very much.

Comment: Ok, but on the Go Stack Overflow, one should encourage the *officially documented idioms*, not one's own opinions of style, particularly in a language as officially opinionated on style as Go.

Comment: @Kaedys I have a rule about style fights: know what's worth fighting over and burning goodwill on and when. When someone writes a four page answer, the only answer, going waaay further than necessary, and teaching a lot of important style issues, for a -4 question... that's not a good time to show up and nit-pick their variable names.